# Theme and custom resolution reset after every reboot

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, themes, display-resolution

I'm currently having two issues that might be related.

I use Numix as theme and icons.
And then, i have a secondary LCD monitor wich I use as primary and disable the one that is integrated with my laptop. And for having the LCD with a regular resolution I'd added one time long ago.

From nowhere, after one reboot i started to have this error (in short version)

*Could not apply the stored configuration for monitors
none of the selected modes were compatible with the possible modes:*

With this, my custom resolution from the LCD monitor, dissapears, both monitors are mirrored, and theme design dissapears.

Googling a lot, I've found out that if a delete the *monitors.xml* inside *˜/.config* the theme gets restore and if I reboot the machine, I don't get the error. BUT

When I'm going to change the monitor preferences as I want to, the monitors.xml gets created, and if i reboot, everything goes bananas again.

Some specs in case that helps

Ubuntu 16.04
Compaq CQ40-500la
SamsungSyncMaster 943NWX

Help?

Cheers